# Create and read key-value in aws secret manager using aws cdk

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, aws-cdk

Please accept my apologies if this question is not proper. But I am badly stuck in task.

I have to crate a stack using aws cdk (python) in which I need to create and read key-value pair in aws-secret manager. I need to add multiple values. Like we can create manually in below image.

[image]

I read multiple articles but unfortunately, I am not able to achieve any thing. Can anyone please help me, how stack can be created which fulfill the requirement?

Following are the articles:
[Link 1](https://betterprogramming.pub/managing-secrets-with-aws-cloud-development-kit-cdk-25ec1e80dfc3)

[Link 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_secretsmanager/README.html)

[Link 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_secretsmanager/Secret.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching more, I have found following link which solves the issue.

[solution](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html)
[Solution 2](https://hands-on.cloud/working-with-secrets-manager-in-python-using-boto3/)